# Find all words with 3 letters with regex

Tags: java, regex, string, parsing

I'm trying to find all words with 3 letters in a string.
So in this list

```
cat monkey dog mouse
```

I only want

```
cat dog
```

This is my expression:

```
^[a-zA-Z]{3}$
```

I tested it with different online regex tester, but none of them matched my expression.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should use your match with word boundaries instead of anchors:

```
\b[a-zA-Z]{3}\b
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hQ4dC4/2)

When you use:

```
^[a-zA-Z]{3}$
```

It means you want to match a line with exact 3 letters.

Comment: in some languages/platforms `\b` is known not to be 100% reliable. So what I would recommend, is to use lookahead/lookbehind something like this: `(?<!\w)\w{3}(?!\w)`

Comment: But there are far more regex platforms supporting world boundary than look-behind feature.

Comment: not sure about that. All the popular ones do support lookahead/lookbehind, when `\b` works just for basic latin symbols. So it is totally unsuitable for, say, cyrillic.

Comment: Word boundary is full supported in Java, no need to worry about look-arounds. @leetwinski: You can't say Javascript is not popular but it has no support for look-behind.

Comment: right you are. My bad. Thought it was supported in js. But still `\b` is unsuitable in many cases. Probably some must use capturing groups then.

Comment: No you can't use `String#matches` as that requires you to match the whole input. Use `Pattern` and `Matcher` API and get your matches using `while (matcher.find()) {...}` loop. Also I fail to understand the reason of removing acceptance mark. I always try my best to respond to comments/doubts.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `.` instead of `[a-zA-Z]` if you want to match any character (also numbers):

```
 \b.{3}\b
```

Answer (score 1):

1. To match all words with 3 letters in a string, the pattern needs to
   be **"\b[a-zA-Z]{3}\b"**
2. The next step would be to compile your pattern.

   ```
   Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\b[a-zA-Z]{3}\\b");
   ```
3. Use a matcher and use the find() and group() methods to print the occurrences

   ```
   for (String word : sentence) {
       Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(word);
       while(matcher.find()) {
           System.out.println(matcher.group());
       }
   }
   ```
4. Your program should look something like -

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       List<String> sentence = new ArrayList<String>();
       sentence.add("cat");
       sentence.add("monkey");
       sentence.add("dog");
       sentence.add("mouse");

       Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\b[a-zA-Z]{3}\\b");

       for (String word : sentence) {
           Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(word);
           while(matcher.find()) {
               System.out.println(matcher.group());
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
grep -e "\b...\b" all-words.txt
```

This works too:

```
grep -E "\b.{3}\b" all-words.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Another suggestion would be to use this pattern:

```
\b\S{3}\b
```

To avoid matching 3 spaces.
This pattern will also match, for example, cyrillic letters.