# Find words with 3 letters in Java

Tags: java, regex, set, hashset

I want to find all words with 3 letters in every element.

In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33017274/find-all-words-with-3-letters-with-regex/33017499#33017499https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33017274/find-all-words-with-3-letters-with-regex/33017499#33017499) I found the right regex, but know I'm trying to get it work in Java.

```
Set<String> input = new HashSet<String>();
input.add("cat 123");
input.add("monkey");
input.add("dog");

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\b[a-zA-Z]{3}\b");

for (String s : input) {
    if (p.matcher(s).matches()) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

In my case I want `cat` and `dog` to be put out, but I only get an empty output.

Comment: backslashes must be escaped (with an other backslash) in a Java string pattern. `\b` => `\\b`

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Ok, in this case I only get `dog`, but `cat` is still missing.

Comment: Yes because cats are more clever. Or perhaps you don't use the good method (`matches` instead of `find`).

Comment: `cat 123` is string containing two words so it doesn't match your regex. You should probably read Java regex tutorial if you want to find `cat`...

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte When using `find` I get the whole string `car 123`.

Comment: Because you print the whole string.

Comment: Sorry, `\b` is the backspace character, ASCII 8.  Perhaps you mean `\\b` (a backslash followed by the `b` char, which means the boundary word operator) ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You have to escape the backslashes, i.e. `\\b` instead of `\b`:

   ```
   Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b[a-zA-Z]{3}\\b");
   ```
2. Create a matcher and use `find` and `group` to find and show the next matched group:

   ```
   for (String s : input) {
       Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
       while (m.find()) {
           System.out.println(m.group());
       }
   }
   ```