# MS Access VBA Function to

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have an MS Access query that I use to place orders for training documents for hospital sites.  I have a table (tblEntSites) with all the sites and the abbreviations that each site uses for the naming convention of their classes.  In order to determine which site is hosting training I need to extract the abbreviation from the "Class_Name" field of our schedule table.  I have been using the below function (although this one is shortened as there are over 20 sites) with a select case statement to do this and it works fine.  However we are constantly adding sites and abbreviations and each time we do this I need to go in and amend the code.  What I would love to be able to do is put together a function that will look to "tblEntSites" instead of the select case statement below.  So basically it would check strClassName against all of the abbreviations in the table and then return the abbreviation that is contained in strClassName.  Thank you in advance for your help!

```
Public Function DetermineSite(strClassName As String) As String

Select Case True

    Case InStr(strClassName, "BMC")
        DetermineSite = "BMC"
    Case InStr(strClassName, "LCC")
        DetermineSite = "LCC"
    Case InStr(strClassName, "RPH")
        DetermineSite = "RPH"
    Case Else
        DetermineSite = "Other"
    End Select

End Function
```

Examples of the "Class_Name" field values, the abbreviation is not always in the same place:

```
ED Unit Coordinator LCC
Ambulatory Nurse 100 BMC (G5)
Ambulatory-HP Health Professional PT/OT 200 RPH (PGL)
```

Comment: `dlookup` or get a recordset of all and use `.filter` `.find`

Comment: yeah DLookup would work wonders for you.  Most likely it'll be INF faster due to that clunky select case.

Comment: Is abbreviation placed in same position in each class name, like first three characters?

Comment: How does your input data (strClassName) look like exactly? A simple Instr() or `Like *...*` seems problematic - `? DetermineSite("Morphelia_LCC")`

Comment: thanks for the quick response guys!  I'm not sure how dlookup would work in this case.  I need to somehow use an instr() function the extract the site abbreviation from the "Class_Name" field.  In the dlookup function the criteria that I would be using for the lookup would be the same value that I would need to return.  I think I need a way to evaluate an instr() function against every value in the abbreviation field in tblEntSites and then stop and return the value when it is true.

Comment: The abbreviation is not in the same place, I have given some examples in my original question.

Comment: I'd suggest something along these lines rather than `instr` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33017274/find-all-words-with-3-letters-with-regex    regular expressions

Comment: Maybe take some time to normalise your database a little?  Put the abbreviations into a separate field (not even sure that counts as normalising) and everything becomes a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

Here try this:

```
  Dlookup("column name", "tbl name", "column name LIKE "*"" & strClassName & """*")
```