# Regex pattern for use with findall() to locate 3 letter words

Tags: python, regex

So I have some code that produces the right result, but the code is too specific. I want it more generic so that I can use re.findall() to extract all 3 letter words from 's2' (for example, DOG).

In the below code, the problem is that I am cherry-picking the three words that are 3 letter words when  I print m[0:3]. In other words, the code I have looks for 3+ letter words and I have to cherry-pick, whereas I just want 3 letters words--no more, no less from the get-go.

```
list2 = 'A, k: it; hi! map@ LAP# rAp, home: LIFE; party! animals@'
m = re.findall(r'(\w{3,})', list2) 
m[0:3]
```

I want to  get ['map', 'lap', 'rAP']. And I want for the code to have ability to retain any other 3, no more no less, letter words in the future.

Comment: Possible dupe :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33017274/find-all-words-with-3-letters-with-regex

Comment: It's okay buddy, regex patterns stretch beyond languages and can be awfully tricky sometimes

Comment: You could loop through each item in the list and turning them to lowercase, then appending them to a new list.

Comment: Create an empty list first, but for example:                                                  for x in list:      newlist.append(x.lower())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look for exactly three word characters, surrounded by word boundaries:

```
import re

s2 = 'I, a: be; go! cat@ DOG# aRe, home: WORK; ninja! rules@'
m = re.findall(r'\b\w{3}\b', s2) 
print(m)
# ['cat', 'DOG', 'aRe']
```

Comment: Hey so this works, but how would I make this lower case so that it is ['cat', 'dog', 'are']....because I tried appending .lower() and that did not work

Comment: I mean, I also tried : [m.lower() for x in ["A","B","C"]] and that did not work either

Comment: I suggest using [regular expressions 101](https://regex101.com/) to experiment with regular expressions, it's a great tool.